# Recompile angularJS component?

Tags: angularjs, compilation, components

I want to recompile / compile the template of my component. I am loading an external module with $onInit, and things just show up when I navigate somewhere else in the page and then back again to the page that loads the module.

I thought that I maybe could compile the template. Do you know a way how I could do that?

---

Edit:

If I use compile in my code, nothing happens

```
controller: {
$onInit(){
this.$ocLazyLoad.load('some.module.js');
 }
},

template:
'<p>Sample text here</p>',

compile: function (tElement, tAttrs) {
    return function(scope) {
        scope.widgetCenter = tAttrs.widgetCenter;
    };

}
```

Answer (score 2):

If the template contents are in a variable "templateContent". You can use the "$compile" service of angular as shown below :

```
$compile(templateContent)(scope);
```

Find the example [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)

Comment: ok... lets say I have a template. I want to $compile that. Where should I add this in my code? Or is it better to create a variable, reference it as my template and then $compile(variable)(scope) ?

Comment: You should do it in your directive, as shown in the example link i've given. If you can share a fiddle or a sample code it'd be helpful. If you think my answer has helped you, please mark it as accepted answer so that we can work on other questions.

Comment: I also read that I could do $compile in a directive, but I am using a component, no directive...